# Existence of a smooth curve joining 3 points

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis, continuity

This is most likely trivial, but I'm not sure of the theorems involved. This is not a homework question.

Suppose I have $3$ points $(0,y_1), (x,y_2), (1,y_3)$, where $x$ is an arbitrary real number between $0$ and $1$, and the y's are complex numbers.

How do I prove that there is function from the real numbers to the complex numbers that is smooth at $x$ (infinitely differentiable at $x$), such that $f(0) = y_1, f(x)=y_2$ and $y(1)=y_3$.

Comment: Hint: Lagrange polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if you have $f(t_k)=z_k$ for $n$ distinct values of $t$, you want $f(t)=c_1(t)z_1+c_2(t)z_2+\cdots+c_n(t)z_n$ and you want it to be the case that

(1) $c_k(t)=1$ when $t=t_k$

and you want it to be the case that

(2) $c_k(t)=0$ if $t=t_j$ for any $j\ne k$.

A coefficient $c_k(t)$ that satisfies both requirements nicely is

\begin{equation}
c_k(t)=\prod_{j\ne k}\left(\dfrac{t-t_j}{t_k-t_j}\right)
\end{equation}

For $f(0)=z_1, f(x)=z_2,f(1)=z_3$ this gives

\begin{equation}
f(t)=\dfrac{(t-1)(t-x)}{(0-1)(0-x)}z_1+\dfrac{(t-0)(t-1)}{(x-0)(x-1)}z_2+\dfrac{(t-0)(t-x)}{(1-0)(1-x)}z_2
\end{equation}

which may be simplified, of course.

Beginning with the third derivative, all higher order derivatives are $0$.